# Storing multiple 2d matricies in one cell array

Tags: matlab

I have multiple variables, which are 2x2 arrays. I would like to stored all these into one cell array is there a for loop that could be used for this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend the following solutions because of the reasons summarised here: https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html.

I'll leave it to you to decide whether it's worth using eval or avoiding it.

(1. Option) If you have A, B, and C representing your 2x2 arrays, then:

```
A = rand(2);
B = rand(2);
C = rand(2);

array_names = ["A", "B", "C"];

D = cell(1, numel(array_names));
for ii = 1:numel(D)
    D{ii} = eval(array_names(ii));
end
```

Should you have more than 3 arrays, just extend array_names accordingly.

(2. Option) If you have A1, A2, and A3 representing your 2x2 arrays, then:

```
A1 = rand(2);
A2 = rand(2);
A3 = rand(2);

D = cell(1, 3);
for ii = 1:numel(D)
    D{ii} = eval("A"+ii);
end
```

Should you have more than 3 arrays, just change the size of the allocated cell D accordingly.